Triggering Cell Change when using a component as the editable Custom Type in Lightning Datatable
A while back, I was able to get the custom picklist type to work in a Lighting DataTable
To do that, the template contained a combo box with this markup:
 <lightning-combobox name="picklist2"
                        data-inputable="true"
                        label={typeAttributes.label}
                        value={editedValue}
                        placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder}
                        options={typeAttributes.options}
                        variant='label-hidden'
                        dropdown-alignment="auto">
    </lightning-combobox>

In the current iteration, I want to use my own LWC to display a Multi Value picklist option. It is mostly working - but unlike the combo box version, I can't get the cellchange to register the new value, nor get the cell background to change to yellow when it changes
I used this MVP implementation, and implemented it like this in the template:
<c-multi-select-combobox
            name="picklistmvp"
            data-inputable="true"
            label={typeAttributes.label}
           
            placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder}
            options={typeAttributes.options}
            currentvalue={typeAttributes.value}
            editvalue={editedValue}
            context={typeAttributes.context}
            show-pills=true
    >
    </c-multi-select-combobox>

and have been able to get the change event in the MVP component to send a custom event back to the parent table, but although the change does trigger the cellchange event when you tab away, only the Id value is shown, there are no field names in the draftValues event details. And the cell doesn't indicate it has changed.
I've tried various attempts to trigger it (manually update draft values, trigger cell change manually) but to no avail.
Is there some trick to using a component like this as the inline edit option such that it will trigger the oncellchange\draftvalue logic like the other components do?
